# MySQL "Table 'X' is read only"

Tags: mysql, redhat, read-only

I'm currently trying to migrate a bunch of databases from one server to another (both servers are running the exact same versions of mysql).  Every night I do a backup using mysqlhotcopy. I've copied the backups (all databases, including mysql) via rsync to the new server.  Now I get a slew of tables that are read only and I can't do anything to fix it.

What I know: the permissions and owners of the moved database are correct.  They're both mysql.mysql and it has proper read/write permissions to the tables (660).  I've flushed the privileges, status, tables, tables with read lock.  I've tried various repairs (repair table blah; repair table blah use_frm;) with no luck.

I'm out of ideas and my searches are coming back with all the same suggestions.

(This also has me curious if I ever had to restore from these copies if I would run into the same massive problem.)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it.  I'll leave out the vast majority of expletives that left my mouth over the past 5 minutes, but SELinux was the culprit.  Now that that piece of #@$@!# is off, everything works.